# Can I make Vim display correct indentation of a PHP file without actually changing the file?

Tags: vim, indentation

I am working with a team that has no standards of indentation: some use spaces and some use tabs.

I know there is a way to correct the indentation in Vim (cindent), but I would rather not change the files.

Is there a way to cause Vim to show PHP file as if they were indented correctly without changing the actual indentation.

Comment: A better idea might be to talk to your team and come up with some standards...

Comment: I think they use Eclipse, which I guess, has an option to conceal the problem from them. So for them, it's a non-issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a copy of the file and indent that one correctly. Alternatively, you could also open a new empty buffer in vim (which has no file name) with `:new` (or `vnew` if you want it in a split) and paste the contents of the file you would like to correctly indent there. Then you can do things to the empty buffer without altering the original file.

Comment: To add to @Zach's answer, the plugin https://github.com/chrisbra/NrrwRgn, can help cut out a chunk of code into its own buffer/window, where you can edit/reindent in isolation. After you're done, it'll automatically insert the modified code back into the original file.